# Create a url path string from dropdown lists selection to dynamically update a Highcharts wind rose chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to JS and trying to update a Highcharts wind rose chart based on the time range selection from three dropdown lists: **year**, **month** and **week**. I'm not sure if that's the best way to achieve that to dynamically update the chart (would the chart reload properly upon change in selection?) ... but the idea is that the user selects these three values to dynamically create a master url path string that will be used to parse the json file locally and update the chart.

My json files are structured as follows:

```
mydata /
--- 2018 /
------- 2018_mean.json
------- january /
    --------------january_mean.json
    --------------week1_mean.json
    --------------week2_mean.json
    --------------week3_mean.json
    --------------week4_mean.json
    --- february /
    --------------february_mean.json
    --------------week5_mean.json
    --------------week6_mean.json
    --------------week7_mean.json
    --- march /
    -------------- ...
    ...
```

So the idea is to construct a local url path based on the values from the three dropdown filters so that, for example, if someone selects 2020 in **year**, none in **month** and none in **week**, the url path should return `'mydata/2020/2020_mean.json'`. Else, if the user selects 2020, January and none for **week**, it should return `'mydata/2020/january/january_mean.json'`. Else if the user selects 2020, January, and Week3 it should return `'mydata/2020/january/week3_mean.json'`.

One more trick, I'm using Django and fetching the json file from a local static file, and the script in the html reads it as such: `fetch("{% static 'mylocalfile.json' %}")`. So how should I edit this line to dynamically pass the master url path in place of 'mylocalfile.json' ?

Lastly, I'd like to use a split dropdown list so that by default the dropdown lists display the current year, none for **month** and none for **week**, i.e, fetching `'mydata/2021/2021_mean.json'`.

Would that be the best way to dynamically update the chart ?

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi @Joss, Your implementation should depend on amount of data. You can consider if it is more efficient to load all data at once and only attach the selected part to the chart. If you need help with constructing the path, please provide me with some minimal live example with selects. You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nf51wprg/

Comment: Many thanks! Here's the JSFiddle link with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/ssoj_tellig/zo85r30x/10/

Comment: Hello, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ytfob8a/ is that something that you are looking for?

Comment: Brilliant - this is perfect! Many thanks :-)